# Printing to a remote computer

Tags: printing

I've been trying to install my network printer and have tried doing it via HPLIP. It doesn't work. So I'm wondering if I can print through IP without adding the printer. I also need to print to remote printers at work when I am at home.

Having the IP of a remote printer, how can I print to it via terminal?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130190/linux-print-directly-to-network-printer-that-is-not-installed

Comment: The second answer worked perfectly. Just a note that one needs to first write "sudo apt-get install netcat" and then "cat you_file.prn | netcat -w 1 printer_ip 9100"... Thank you very much for your great help!!! :-)

Comment: Great please write up an answer!

Answer (score 1):

First run:

```
sudo apt-get install netcat
```

And then:

```
sudo cat my_file.pdf | netcat -w 1 printer_ip 9100
```

This worked perfectly for me :-)